# Why am I getting an error with my PowerShell Invoke-SQLCMD InputFile?

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd, invoke-sqlcmd

I am trying to invoke SQLCMD from a PowerShell script but Powershell does not seem to like how I am passing -InputFile to Invoke-Sqlcmd. MY code looks something like this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $regex};
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $files[0].FullName
```

$files is never empty as printing $files[0].FullName outputs a string like "D:\foo\foo.sql". When my application reaches this line, it throws an error pointing to the same line that I use Invoke-Sqlcmd and the character of the "$" in "$files".

I receives these two error messages:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : The pipeline has been stopped.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], PipelineStoppedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Invoke-Sqlcmd : An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

Is there an issue with how I am feeding the filepath of the script I want to run? What would be the correct format. I have also tried to use .PSPath instead of .FullName but I get an error saying that the file path is not supported.

Comment: This is an error that is the result of commands in your script, as can be recognized from the `SqlError`, and so it probably has nothing to do with what you do in PowerShell. You can get this, for example, with `SELECT 1 WHERE 1`, as `1` is not valid as a condition.